# HTML multiple form inside and outside DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to do something like following:

```
<div id="div1"....>
   <div id="div2"....>
      <form name="form1" .....>
         <input type="text">
         <input type="submit" value="submit1">
      </form>

      <form name="form2" .....>
         <input type="text">
   </div>  //End of Div2
   <div id="div3" ...>
         <input type="submit"  value="submit2"......>
      </form> //End of form2
   </div> //End of Div3
</div> //End of Div1
```

But everytime the `form` closing is going inside of `div2`. As a result the `submit input` is coming out of the `form` and the `form` is not being submitted after click. Please help.

My `div` positions are here according to my project need. Is there any way to maintain the `form` opening inside the `div` and `submit` button/closing outside the `div`??

Comment: that is invalid html syntax

Comment: why would you do that?  It's completely invalid markup.  Are you able to explain why this is needed so that we can provide alternative solutions?

Comment: You say you `div` position is per you project needs. What is greater priority, arbitrary positionig of the div's in the HTML or providing a form that functions as desired? With invlid markup you are opening yourslef up to inconsistent results. Take a step back from the code. Look at the big picture. Think about how you would approach the desired result given a blank page. The only reason to stick with this approach is if it a contraint of a content managment system like WordPress etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your opening and closing tags for `form` should be inside the same `div` parent

try something like this:

```
<div id="div1"....>
   <div id="div2"....>
      <form name="form1" .....>
         <input type="text">
         <input type="submit" value="submit1">
      </form>
   </div>  //End of Div2
   <div id="div3" ...>
      <form name="form2" .....>
         <input type="text">
         <input type="submit"  value="submit2"......>
      </form> //End of form2
   </div> //End of Div3
</div> //End of Div1
```

Comment: I can't re-position the div. This is according to the page design from my customer because she has created multiple tabs in design but with same submit button

Comment: @Ray your customer shouldn't care about the mark up (appart from being assured it is good quility), only that the functionality and desired look is achived, i.e.  Forms in tabs. It's up to us a devlopers to achieve that in the most efficient and maintainable way we know how. If a customer provides me with their own mock up in HTML, I'm prepared to through the whole lot out if I think it can be done better. I'm looking at you, those clients who proved mock ups using table based design!

Comment: I'd also be looking at using `fieldsets` for your tab containers. It's more semantic and you may be able to use the `legend` for the tab tag.

Comment: @JonP Sorry to say, My div positions are here according to my project need. It will be helpful if you let me know is there any way to maintain the form opening inside the div and submit button/closing form outside the div?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this.

```
<div id="div1"....>
   <div id="div2"....>
      <form name="form1" .....>
         <input type="text">
         <input type="submit" value="submit1">
      </form>

      <form name="form2" .....>
         <input type="text">   
   <div id="div3" ...>
         <input type="submit"  value="submit2"......>
   </div>  //End of Div3
      </form> //End of form2
   </div> //End of Div2
</div> //End of Div1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need exactly but I cleaned it up a little bit, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
<div id="div1">
       <form> 
            <input type="text" name="from1">
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit1">
       </form>
</div>
<div id="div2"> 
       <form> 
            <input type="text" name="from2">
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit2">
       </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very similar to @Rami.Shareef answer and does not address any of the issues raised in comments or the sentence *My div positions are here according to my project need. Is there any way to maintain the form opening inside the div and submit button/closing outside the div??*.